# Parsing command-line arguments without ignoring backslash

Tags: perl, arguments, command-line-arguments, backslash

I need to take the first element of ARGV and save it as my template for searching through files. This element contains a backslash `/` but when I save it in a variable, the backslash disappears:

```
my $template = $ARGV[0];
print $template;
```

prints out GGCC, while the first argument is GG\CC. How can I get around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't really a `perl` problem, it's your shell.

Try typing:

```
echo \fish
```

And you'll see the output:

```
fish
```

`perl` has the same problem - it's not even seeing that slash in the first place, because the shell is processing the line for escapes and quote first.

The only thing you can change is the invocation. Add an extra slash to the invocation:

```
echo \\fish
```

And you'll get:

```
\fish
```

Comment: or quote it. `echo '\fish'`